# Renaming Linux files that accidentally have multiple .mp3 extensions

Tags: rename

I screwed up and accidentally have a bunch of files with the extension `.mp3.mp3.mp3.mp3`

How can I change these, recursively—and over multiple directories—to set them to just `.mp3`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a fairly simple solution, which is to just cut off everything from the first ".mp3" and then add ".mp3" back on. So:

```
for file in $(find . -name "*.mp3"); do mv "$file" "${file%%.mp3*}.mp3"; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the `rename` utility that comes with perl (might be known as `perl-rename` on some systems), and a shell with `**` (zsh, or bash with `shopt -s globstar`, among others):

```
rename 's/(\.mp3)+$/.mp3/' /somedir/**/*.mp3
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) command in `bash` and some creative scripting, this can be magically cleaned up. The following scripts were tested on Mac OS X 10.9.5 but should work fine on Linux as well. First run this as a “dry run” to make sure you are targeting the right files:

```
find '/path/to/your/files' -type f -name '*.mp3.mp3*' |\
  while read RAW_FILE
  do
    DIRNAME=$(dirname "$RAW_FILE")
    BASENAME=$(basename "$RAW_FILE")
    FILENAME="${BASENAME%%.*}"
    EXTENSION="${BASENAME#*.}"
    echo "mv "${RAW_FILE}" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME}".mp3"
  done
```

You should first change the `/path/to/your/files` to match the actual path to the affected files on the system. Also note the last line which is an [`echo`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/echo) of an [`mv`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mv) (move) command. I am doing this to make sure that the script is targeting the correct files.

The core `find` logic is this:

```
find '/path/to/your/files' -type f -name '*.mp3.mp3*'
```

Which basically means, “Find all files in the path `/path/to/your/files` that are actually files (and not directories) that have a filename pattern that matches `*.mp3.mp3*`. That should catch any/all files that have more than one `.mp3` attached to them; `.mp3.mp3`, `.mp3.mp3.mp3`,  `.mp3.mp3.mp3.mp3`, `.mp3.mp3.mp3.mp3.mp3`, etc…

The script won’t bother to deal with files that just have the correct `.mp3` which is a definitely speed benefit if you only have a small subset of files misnamed `.mp3.mp3.mp3.mp3` instead of having to rename all files with `.mp3`.

So when you run that you should see a list of “dry run” `mv` commands that will fix your issue: Find all those multiple `.mp3` files and rename them to a proper, singular `.mp3`.

Now that that works good, just run the final script like this:

```
find '/path/to/your/files' -type f -name '*.mp3.mp3*' |\
  while read RAW_FILE
  do
    DIRNAME=$(dirname "$RAW_FILE")
    BASENAME=$(basename "$RAW_FILE")
    FILENAME="${BASENAME%%.*}"
    EXTENSION="${BASENAME#*.}"
    mv "${RAW_FILE}" "${DIRNAME}/${FILENAME}".mp3
  done
```

Note that the last line is the actual, functional `mv` command. When you run this version of the script your whole directory will be searched for those multiple `.mp3` files and then actually run the full `mv` command to fix the issue.

Comment: +1, your answer is better than mine. ;-)